# Book about a company finding your reincarnation

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book but I only read the synopsis, which goes like this:

In our society a company pretends that reincarnation is a thing.
For a large sum of money they can, after your death, find the new body you inhabit so you can keep the possessions you had in your previous life.

The synopsis ended by asking some questions about how this could affect the world we live in. Is this just a hoax ? Can and should the governments do something about that ? If only rich people can now virtually live forever, what will the social repercussions be ?

I'm quite sure I read that in French.

Comment: Does the company pretend that reincarnation is a thing, or is it an actual thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Reborn Express* (2019) by Christian Féron.

It's available for free on [the author's website](http://chrisferon.free.fr/romans/reborn-express-roman.php). Most of the translation of the summary courtesy of DeepL:

> **Thanks to cutting-edge technology, Reborn Express offers an original service to the richest men: after their death, locate their reincarnation to pass on their own fortune**, so that they can be reborn in the best possible conditions.
>
> The cheapest price starts at one million dollars. Could this be one of the biggest scams of the century?
>
> But governments around the world are asking: **if this is not a scam, should Reborn Express be left unchecked**, since there are no laws regulating life after death?
>
> Indeed, with this process, **those at the top of society will remain eternally rich**, while the others will have to make do with  crumbs forever...
>
> With a revolution looming, who will put an end to this madness? Morgan the anarchist, or the brilliant inventor of the planned renaissance, René Niederhauser?

---

Found with the Google query `roman science fiction entreprise business reincarnation société` (`scifi novel company business reincarnation society`), the second page of the Google results brought up [this review](https://www.monbestseller.com/actualites-litteraire-conseil/11586-reborn-express-publie-par-christian-feron-science-fiction) (French).

Comment: That's it ! Thanks a lot !